# Is Propel caching criteria when getting related objects?

Tags: php, propel

I have a Propel 1.6 generated class Group that has Inits related to it, and Inits have Resps related to them. Pretty straightforward.

I don't understand the difference between these two pieces of Propel code. Here in the first one, I re-create the `$notDeleted` criteria on every loop. This code does what I want -- it gets all the Resps into the `$data` array.

```
foreach ($group->getInits() as $init) {
    $notDeleted = RespQuery::create()->filterByIsDeleted(false);
    foreach ($init->getResps($notDeleted) as $resp) {
        $data[] = $resp;
    }
}
```

Here in the second code, I had the `$notDeleted` criteria pulled out of the loop, for (what I thought were) obvious efficiency reasons. This code does not work the way I want -- it only gets the Resps from one of the Inits.

```
$notDeleted = RespQuery::create()->filterByIsDeleted(false);
foreach ($group->getInits() as $init) {
    foreach ($init->getResps($notDeleted) as $resp) {
        $data[] = $resp;
    }
}
```

I thought it must be something to do with how the `getResps()` method caches the results, but that's not how the docs or the code reads in that method. The docs and the code say that if the criteria passed in to `getResps()` is not null, it will always get the results from the database. Maybe some other Propel cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First off, I'm guessing you meant to use `$init` versus `$initiative` in your loops. That or there's some other code we're not seeing here.)

Here's my guess: In your second example you pull out the `$notDeleted` `Criteria` object, but each time through the inner `foreach` the call to `getResps($notDeleted)` is going to make Propel do a `filterByInit()` on the `Criteria` instance with the current `Init` instance. This will add a new `WHERE` condition to the SQL, but obviously a `Resp` can only have one `Init.Id` value, hence the lone result.

I don't think there is a good reason to pull that out though, under the covers Propel is just creating a new Criteria object, cloning the one you pass in - thus no real memory saved.

Comment: (Yes, you were right about the variable name, thanks to j0k for cleaning it up.) I'm sort of seeing what you're saying. But I would have expected Propel to generate a new WHERE Init.Id = ? condition each time in the loop. But I guess it wasn't doing that?

Comment: I don't think it would... but I'm not 100% sure. There could be something else going on, but even if so, I don't think it would be your code that is the culprit.